# How to Protect SQL Server 2005?

Tags: windows, sql-server

My project's backend is `SQL Server 2005` and I need to install this to customers' systems.

The problem is when someone logs onto the computer, they can easily access the SQL Server with Windows authentication. How can I protect the SQL server from local logins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to stop Windows local admins from accessing SQL server - see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34684/restrict-access-for-windows-administrator.

By default, users who are not local admins will not be able access SQL Server with Windows Authentication. So the solution for you is to ensure your users are not local admins.